# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting an error when trying to `edit` an `Article`. Here is my error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#edit
```

**articles.controller.rb**

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
   @article = Article.new
  end

  def edit
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
   @article = Article.new(article_params)
   if @article.save
     flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully created"
     redirect_to article_path(@article)
   else
     render 'new'
   end
  end

 def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  if @article.update
    flash[:notice] = "Article was successfully updated"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
 end

 def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 end
```

Comment: its unable to find Article with passed id. What does the url look like? Is there an article with passed ID in the database?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#edit
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=9

Extracted source (around line #8):
6
7
8
9
10
11
              

 def edit
  @article =Article.find(params[:id])
end



Rails.root: /home/nitrous/code/rails_projects/alpha-blog

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:8:in `edit'

Comment: it seems, there is no record in database with id = 9. You need to have an article before you can edit it. you can use rails console to list/create new article object.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass the `@article` into the url. You should have a url similar to this:

```
<%= link_to "Edit Article", edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

Also be sure to check your database and make sure that an `Article` is actually saving. I don't see your `article_params` but I assume they are defined as you are using them in your `create` method.

Your **routes.rb** looks something like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :articles
end
```